# What went wrong with my cookie dough?

Tags: baking

[image: Cookie Dougn]

This is my latest attempt at making chewy cookies.

I used:

- 220 g butter, melted
- 200 g brown sugar
- 100 g white sugar
- 320 g all-purpose flour 320g
- 1 whole egg + 1 yolk

I don't understand why it turned to a dark color. Is it because of the brown sugar? Chewy cookies need a high brown to white ratio, don't they?

One more thing I noticed while mixing was that the sugar (both white and brown) didn't mix easily with the melted butter.

Also, are *chewy cookie* and *softbaked cookie* the same thing?

Here's the result after baking for 12 minutes
[image: top][image: bottom][image: inside]
form the look of its bottom i think there might be something wrong during beating sugar in melted butter,isn't it?

Comment: What's wrong? It looks like cookie dough to me. What happens when you bake it?

Comment: How did you mix your cookie dough?  Even though most modern recipes use melted butter instead of softened butter, the way the ingredients are combined can make a difference in how the dough comes together.  Typically the sugar and butter are mixed with the egg added in stages - this should be done before the dry ingredients are added because it give the lecithin in the egg yolks time to emulsify the fat into the liquid from the butter and egg white - if your cookie dough came out greasy, it was probably because the fat hadn't sufficiently emulsified in your mixture.

Comment: now it's in the fridge. I'll bake it tomorrow but i predict that it'll come out very greasy.

Comment: I think the ratios are wrong. Where did you get the recipe? Also no shortening? I learned to add the eggs AFTER mixing the sugars and butter/shortening.

Comment: Might be the ratios thing exactly. I couldn't figure it out what is the proper ratios between dry and wet ingredients.

Comment: So you didn't use a recipe? You just improvised?

Comment: I used this recipe but with room temp. butter, everything come out quite alright except its cakey texture so i tried with melted butter hoping that it might help improve the texture.

Comment: Is there no leavening in your recipe? Your recipe doesn't list baking powder or baking soda.

Comment: No. I didn't put in any of those because i don't want it too cakey.

Comment: You can't just leave them out!  You still want it to rise a little bit... otherwise you just end up with a rock... which you did (per your own comments).

Answer (score 2):

Your egg and butter mix has curdled/split you need to put it in a fresh floured bowl and keep mixing till smooth.

The brown is, as you mentioned, the brown sugar. Nothing to worry about.

Personally I wouldn't use melted butter at all. Rather I would use soft butter. Creaming sugar and butter with melted butter is impossible, especially if the butter is melted to the extent where the fat and milk have separated.

Soft bake is soft, like cake. Chewy bake is ... Chewy, like brownies.

Comment: Note - sugar cannot be "creamed" with melted butter - creaming refers to a process of using crystalline sugar to beat air into softened butter.

Comment: So when i use melted butter do i have to wait until it cool down completely before dumping the sugar in?

Comment: There are plenty of recipes that use melted butter. You just have to use a recipe that expects it.

Comment: @SukanokDonot Yes, the butter should be heated just enough to barely melt and then allowed to cool down again.

Comment: I melted it until it turn liquid state. However, I remember watching from some website they use completely melted butter but the result is far better than mine. My cookies looks just like rocks from Mar.

Answer (score 1):

The Cooks Country recipe for [Chewy Chocolate Chip Cookies](http://www.cookscountry.com/recipes/7847-thick-and-chewy-chocolate-chip-cookies?) is very similar to the one you're using. For the purpose of method comparison and ratios I'm putting it here. I've adjusted what measurements I can to metric.

It's behind a paywall, unfortunately but I'll put it here for now... If I should remove it, please let me know.

As you may notice everything is pretty much the same except the butter is 50% greater than in yours 340 grams instead of 220 grams.

Hopefully, seeing the method here along with adding some extra butter should help you be more successful the next time.

- 300 g all-purpose flour
- 1/2 teaspoon baking soda
- 1/2 teaspoon salt
- 340 g unsalted butter, melted and **cooled**
- 200 g light brown sugar
- 100 g granulated sugar
- 1 large egg plus 1 large yolk
- 2 teaspoons vanilla extract
- 250 g semisweet chocolate chips

Instructions

1. Adjust oven rack to lower-middle position and heat oven to 160 degrees C. Line 2 baking sheets with parchment paper. Combine flour, baking soda, and salt in bowl.
2. Using stand mixer fitted with paddle, beat melted butter, brown sugar, and granulated sugar on medium speed until smooth, about 2 minutes. Add egg and yolk and vanilla and beat until combined. Reduce speed to low and add flour mixture in 3 additions until just combined, scraping down bowl as needed. Stir in chocolate chips by hand.
3. Working with 2 tablespoons dough at a time, roll into balls and space them 2 inches apart on prepared sheets. Bake cookies, 1 sheet at a time, until edges are set and beginning to brown but centers are still soft and puffy, 15 to 20 minutes, rotating sheet halfway through baking. Let cookies cool on sheets for 10 minutes before serving.

Comment: Thank you very much.
The hard part for me is "just combined" part. I don't know exactly when to stop. With melted butter, Do you mean completely melted to liquid,right?

Comment: @SukanokDonot I usually put my butter in the microwave and zap it for 20 seconds, stir, and then continue to slowly melt it in 10 second increments until, by stirring, the whole thing is melted. This should only take about 40 - 50 seconds, depending on your microwave. Don't overheat it, you want it cool anyway, so just barely bring it to the melting point.

Comment: @SukanokDonot **Just combined** means you mix it slowly until right when you can't see any of the flour. You have a little wriggle room but stirring is what activates the gluten and you don't want that, so you're only going to stir until it looks homogenous and no longer!

Comment: Thank you for your comments ..
You mean it suppose to look creamy not turn all liquid, right?
and mixing wet and dry ingredients, which do you think better between dumping wet in dry ingredient or vice versa?

Comment: @SukanokDonot I just saw your question. The butter just has to have no solid bits left... I still consider that totally liquid... you just don't want it to separate. It's generally easier to mix dry into wet, as you don't have to worry about leaving unmixed dry ingredients in the bottom of the bowl. It's the standard process.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i melted butter until fat separate from butter.